# Hiding buttons in cells

Tags: ios, swift2

I am developing app which users will choose one of the two pictures in one cell. My prototype cell looks like :

[image]

and I have

```
cell.rightVoteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(voteRightButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

cell.leftVoteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(voteLeftButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

in the `tableView` function.

```
func voteRightButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){

    print("Right Vote clicked is \(sender.tag)")
    print(self.polls[sender.tag].poll_id)

}
```

in this way I am printing the polls id and cells index.

I want to hide the Vote button after clicking specific cell. 
For example if I click the vote in first cell and the left picture, I want to hide the two buttons on the first cell. I now the cell's index but how can hide the buttons in specific cell.

My Custom TableViewCell:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPicture: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!



    @IBOutlet weak var pollDescription: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using tags, which have no intrinsic meaning and are easy to confuse, you can say something like:

```
func voteRightButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    let location = self.tableView.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, fromView:sender)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)
    if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomUITableViewCell {

    //hide views in cell and update your model to reflect vote.
    }
    print("Right Vote clicked is \(indexPath.row)")
    print(self.polls[indexPath.row].poll_id)

}
```

Once you have the cell you can hide the views you want and you can update your model to reflect the vote just cast.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a tableview with several cells of this type, if this is the case you need a custonTableViewCell where you put this code. the buttons respond to a @IBAction that hide the buttons and call a delegate in his UITableViewController.

understand your custonTableViewCell like a viewController for each cell

add this in your custon cell and point the button

// IBAction for buttons

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: UIButton){
    leftButton.hidden = true
    rightImage.hidden = true
    self.delegate?.buttonPress(sender.tag)
}
```

add this before your custon cell class definition

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
   func buttonPress(tag: Int)
}
```

and this after:

```
var delegate : CustomTableViewCellDelegate?
```

and in your tableviewcontroller

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomTableViewCellDelegate
```

and your new func in some place

```
func buttonPress(tag: Int){
    print(tag)
}
```

Comment: I add my Custom TableViewCell in my post